# How to allow node authors to mark the best comment and to promote this comment on the top of list

Tags: rules, comments

In my project comments are prices so its important that commenters see author's choice. I want to allow authors to choose the best comment that would get this comment promoted on the top of a comments list. Can I do it with Rules or some other ways?

Comment: Is the node author the only person who can choose the best comment? Will he only pick one comment as the best? If so, you can probably use the Flag module (https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and the Views module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views)  for this.

Comment: well, i have created global flag for comments and it works nice. Its nice that it offers as option  permission to use flag only for node authors.Now i need some action or rule to be triggered to promote flagged comment on top (change the weight in list). Which  action or rule i should look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, you can create a global [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), say *Best price*, for comments. In order to reorder the comments, you can create a comment [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) which displays all comments of a certain node with the flagged ones on top. Afterwards, display the associated block on the node's page.

Maybe there is an easier way to reorder the comments, but this should at least work and illustrate the strength of the Views module. Underneath is my exported View, which you can easily import and adapt to your needs if necessary:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'reordered_comments';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'comment';
$view->human_name = 'Reordered comments';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access comments';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'comment';
/* Relationship: Comment: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Relationship: Flags: best_price */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'best_price';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['user_scope'] = 'any';
/* Field: Comment: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['id'] = 'subject';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['field'] = 'subject';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Comment: Comment */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['id'] = 'comment_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['table'] = 'field_data_comment_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['field'] = 'comment_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Comment: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Sort criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['flagged']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['flagged']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Comment: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_argument_type'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Comment: Approved */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
```

Comment: It worked. Added your view to my node panel layout, placed it above comments list and that's it. I also decided that it'd be nice to exclude  the flagged comment from list so I added alternative view of comments for that.